# Is it possible to intercept an action from becoming a ContentResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to write a filter that wraps data to follow the [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#status) and so far I've got it working on all cases where I directly return an ActionResult, such as `ComplexTypeJSON`. I am trying to get it to work in situations like `ComplexType` where I do not have to run the `Json` function constantly.

```
[JSONAPIFilter]
public IEnumerable<string> ComplexType()
{
    return new List<string>() { "hello", "world" };
}

[JSONAPIFilter]
public JsonResult ComplexTypeJSON()
{
    return Json(new List<string>() { "hello", "world" });
}
```

However, by the time `public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)` runs when I navigate to `ComplexType`, the `filterContext.Result` is a Content Result, that is just a string where `filterContext.Result.Content` is simply:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"
```

Is there a way I can set something up to make `ComplexType` become `JsonResult` rather than `ContentResult`?

For context, here are the exact files:

TestController.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    using MyProject.Filters;

    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [JSONAPIFilter]
        public IEnumerable<string> ComplexType()
        {
            return new List<string>() { "hello", "world" };
        }

        [JSONAPIFilter]
        public JsonResult ComplexTypeJSON()
        {
            return Json(new List<string>() { "hello", "world" });
        }

        // GET: Test
        [JSONAPIFilter]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Json(new { foo = "bar", bizz = "buzz" });
        }

        [JSONAPIFilter]
        public string SimpleType()
        {
            return "foo";
        }

        [JSONAPIFilter]
        public ActionResult Throw()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Some issue");
        }
    }
}
```

JSONApiFilter.cs

```
namespace MyProject.Filters
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    using MyProject.Exceptions;
    using MyProject.Models.JSONAPI;

    public class JSONAPIFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        private static readonly ISet<Type> IgnoredTypes = new HashSet<Type>()
                                                              {
                                                                  typeof(FileResult),
                                                                  typeof(JavaScriptResult),
                                                                  typeof(HttpStatusCodeResult),
                                                                  typeof(EmptyResult),
                                                                  typeof(RedirectResult),
                                                                  typeof(ViewResultBase),
                                                                  typeof(RedirectToRouteResult)
                                                              };

        private static readonly Type JsonErrorType = typeof(ErrorModel);

        private static readonly Type JsonModelType = typeof(ResultModel);

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (IgnoredTypes.Any(x => x.IsInstanceOfType(filterContext.Result)))
            {
                base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
                return;
            }

            var resultModel = ComposeResultModel(filterContext.Result);
            var newJsonResult = new JsonResult()
                                    {
                                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                                        Data = resultModel
                                    };

            filterContext.Result = newJsonResult;
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

            if (modelState == null || modelState.IsValid)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ModelStateException("Errors in ModelState");
            }
        }

        public virtual void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (filterContext.Exception == null) return;

            // Todo: if modelstate error, do not provide that message
            // set status code to 404

            var errors = new List<string>();

            if (!(filterContext.Exception is ModelStateException))
            {
                errors.Add(filterContext.Exception.Message);
            }

            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            var modelStateErrors = modelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList();
            if (modelStateErrors.Any()) errors.AddRange(modelStateErrors);

            var errorCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            var errorModel = new ErrorModel()
                                 {
                                     status = errorCode.ToString(),
                                     detail = filterContext.Exception.StackTrace,
                                     errors = errors,
                                     id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                     title = filterContext.Exception.GetType().ToString()
                                 };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = errorCode;

            var newResult = new JsonResult() { Data = errorModel, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

            filterContext.Result = newResult;
        }

        private ResultModel ComposeResultModel(ActionResult actionResult)
        {
            var newModelData = new ResultModel() { };

            var asContentResult = actionResult as ContentResult;
            if (asContentResult != null)
            {
                newModelData.data = asContentResult.Content;
                return newModelData;
            }

            var asJsonResult = actionResult as JsonResult;
            if (asJsonResult == null) return newModelData;

            var dataType = asJsonResult.Data.GetType();
            if (dataType != JsonModelType)
            {
                newModelData.data = asJsonResult.Data;
            }
            else
            {
                newModelData = asJsonResult.Data as ResultModel;
            }

            return newModelData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Provide us with more context? Explain more of the terms to those unfamiliar with your JSON API?

Comment: None of this is specific to my JSON API but I have provided the exact files for the filter and test controller.

Comment: so, you are not able to access your list in the `ComposeResultModel` method.Am i correct?

Comment: If you prefer to use an Action Method to return your async requests, why not use the `JSON` ActionResult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1.use **ApiController** instead of **Controller**

The apicontroller will return json result,and the default serializer is **Newtonsoft.json**[(here)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json),so you can use like this below:

```
//the response type
public class SimpleRes
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
    public string Result;      
}

//the controller
 public class TestController : ApiController
 {  
    [HttpGet] 
    [HttpPost]
    [JSONAPIFilter]
    public SimpleRes TestAction()
    {
        return new SimpleRes(){Result = "hello world!"};
    }
 }
```

2.wrap your response with your own **ActionResult** if you insist using **Controller**:

```
//json container
public class AjaxMessageContainer<T>
{        
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "result")]
    public T Result { set; get; }
}

//your own actionresult
public class AjaxResult<T> : ActionResult
{        
    private readonly T _result;                      

    public AjaxResult(T result)
    {          
        _result = result;           
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new AjaxMessageContainer<T>
        {               
            Result = _result,               
        });
        var bytes =
            new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(result);
        context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);           
    }
}

//your controller
[JSONAPIFilter]
public AjaxResult<List<String>> TestSimple()
{
    return AjaxResult<List<String>>(new List<string>() { "hello", "world" });
}
```

and if you wanna get response string from **filter** for log or something:

```
var result  = filterContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: yes, this kind of request should be handled by an API. But what's wrong with sending back the OOB JSON `result`

Comment: Ultimately the combination of the custom actionresult and my filter attribute led to the desired behavior. Thanks for the explanation, it was great!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```
public class JSONAPIFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = ((ViewResult)context.Result).ViewData.Model
        };
    }
}
```

> From @roosteronacid : [return jsonresult in actionfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662216/return-jsonresult-using-an-actionfilter-on-an-actionresult-in-a-controller)

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same issue and found a slightly different approach.
The basic idea was from [NOtherDev](https://gist.github.com/NOtherDev/3766954). 
I would introduce an `IActionInvoker`.

```
public class ControllerActionInvokerWithDefaultJsonResult : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    public const string JsonContentType = "application/json";

    protected override ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue)
    {
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWith("/api/"))
        {
            return (actionReturnValue as ActionResult) 
                ?? new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = actionReturnValue,
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
        }
        return base.CreateActionResult(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, actionReturnValue);
    }
}
```

In this case every request starting with "/api/" will have transformed result to json, however only when the `actionReturnValue` is not a type inherited from `ActionResult` already.

`IActionInvoker` is resolved by `DependencyResolver`, so you need to define the registration in your favorite ioc container which you have set as `DependencyResolver`.

```
myFavoriteContainer.Register<IActionInvoker, ControllerActionInvokerWithDefaultJsonResult>(Lifestyle.Transient);
```

For `JsonResult` you could use the built-in or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086346/3687276).

In a case you are using async action methods you should inherit from `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` instead of `ControllerActionInvoker` and I assume you will need to add an another registration for `IAsyncActionInvoker` as well. I am not sure about changes in the async part of the invoker itself.